# How to calculate Bockstein homomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-topology

For a given coefficients sequence, $0 \to Z \to Z \to Z_2 \to 0$, where the map $Z \to Z $ is defined as times 2.
My question is how to calculate the Bockstein homomorphism for real projective plane and Klein bottle? Thanks!

Comment: This is really a question on homological algebra. I'd recommend Rotman's book "Introduction to Homological Algebra", especially Theorem 6.10 and the succeeding example in the second edition.

Comment: @Tyrone thanks. I know. It’s just a diagram-chasing

Comment: That's *how* to calculate it. You can also just use the fact that $\times 2:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ induces multiplication by 2 on homology groups. Then, if you know the integral and mod 2 cohomology rings of $\mathbb{R}P^2$, the fact you get a long exact sequence gives you the answer for free. You can then use the relation of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ with the Klein bottle to calculate it there.